# It is necessary to compare two Python dictionaries

Tags: python

me need to compare 2 dictionaries using Python, but the problem is that they are of different lengths and me only need to compare .values() at the same time - it is necessary to output information about those values that did not match to process them further.

the idea is this, I have files on my computer and files on my NAS, I need to compare them by sha with each other

example:

```
x = {'C:\\test\\1\\123.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30',
     'C:\\test\\1\\lalala.zip': '45cef0d73b817a890183227c88719af99e68ec47'}
y = {'/var/data/123.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30',
     '/var/data/234.zip': '41b845d81c0c0b4510e356c26206d0f9b118285d',
     '/var/data/345.zip': 'dba1f5a7c1c34327ee261f95b58804ceae5c3577'}
```

expected output:

```
'C:\\test\\1\\lalala.zip': '45cef0d73b817a890183227c88719af99e68ec47' - differ
```

Unfortunately all I found was this:

```
shared_items = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in y and x[k] != y[k]}
print(shared_items)
```

but in my case it doesn't work because of the different lengths and that I only need to compare.values() and output =! values together with the key

please help me, even the GPT chat didn't help me))

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want, could you explain precisely what you mean by "compare"?

Comment: Try to formulate for yourself, what you want to do. Example: for each item in x, check that the value of this item is also a value in y, if so ..., if not .... We cannot help you with understanding what you want, but once you formulated for yourself, you might not even need our help any more.

Comment: Convert the values to sets. Then use the set difference function to get elements of one set that aren't in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse through the first list and compare each value with values in the second list of values.

```
x = {'C:\\test\\1\\123.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30', 'C:\\test\\1\\lalala.zip': '45cef0d73b817a890183227c88719af99e68ec47'}
y = {'/var/data/123.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30', '/var/data/234.zip': '41b845d81c0c0b4510e356c26206d0f9b118285d', '/var/data/345.zip': 'dba1f5a7c1c34327ee261f95b58804ceae5c3577'}

files = {key:value for key, value in x.items() if value not in y.values()}
print(files)
```

This code outputs

```
{'C:\\test\\1\\lalala.zip': '45cef0d73b817a890183227c88719af99e68ec47'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always check the "backup/destination" location.  in your example you probably want to check if files on your computer exist on the nas?

I would also probably use list comprehension because files can have different names with same sha?

```py
x = {
    'C:\\test\\1\\123.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30',
    'C:\\test\\1\\420.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30',
    'C:\\test\\1\\lalala.zip': '45cef0d73b817a890183227c88719af99e68ec47'
}
y = {
    '/var/data/123.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30',
    '/var/data/234.zip': '41b845d81c0c0b4510e356c26206d0f9b118285d',
    '/var/data/345.zip': 'dba1f5a7c1c34327ee261f95b58804ceae5c3577'
}

vals = set(y.values())
shared_items = [{k:v} for k,v in x.items() if v in vals]
print(shared_items)
```

output:

```
[{'C:\\test\\1\\123.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30'},
 {'C:\\test\\1\\420.zip': 'df029a659e13fb455aa3d39079caf4e52e2fcd30'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know what values in x aren't in y then you can use set difference:

```
set(x.values()) - set(y.values())
```

And if you need the keys that correspond to the values you can use the following:

```
x_by_values = dict(zip(x.values(), x))
{x_by_values[v]: v for v in set(x.values()) - set(y.values())}
```